# General rule for htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I was wondering if there is a method in htaccess to rewrite with 301 this kind of links:

Old link: http://sitename.com/article-name_0_10700.html

New link: http://sitename.com/article-name

Unfortunately I don't have all links from site (no sitemap or other things that might help) so i need a general rule for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(.*)-(.*)_(.*)_(.*).html$ /$1-$2 [L,R=301]
```

It should redirect `article-name_0_10700.html` to `article-name`

Comment: No problem, if the answer helped, feel free to mark it as correct so other people who have the same question as you, will know how you solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Using `RedirectMatch`:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/([^_]+)_ /$1
```